# iPhone Automation for 3rd party/built in apps

Tags: android, ios, iphone, testing, automation

I'm trying to find an automation framework for iOS and/or Android that allows me to automate actions on a real device using 3rd party/built-in apps.  For example, I want to be able to automate: Browse these websites with Safari, watch these videos with the Youtube app, et al.

The automation frameworks I've encountered in my search seem to be focused on testing out your own app, in which you provide hooks in your own code to the framework in question.

I won't be testing out my own app (I'm testing out a proxy that the devices send traffic through), and thus won't have access to the source code to the apps on the device.  I'm new to this, apologies in advance if there's a way obvious answer right under my nose.

Comment: Having the same problem, the only option I saw is a commercial solution: eggPlant: http://www.testplant.com/eggplant I did not try it though...

Answer (score 0):

For android automation you can use UIAutomator. It doesn't require source code. It uses in built uiautomator jar file which is present in android SDK. For more information you can refer http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html